# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details magento2 site

Tags: magento2

I am getting this error:

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.

How to get more information that can help solve this?

Comment: Please add details here.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check first error details.

In Magento-2 You can check error while enveloping like below.

Set application developer mode

Run command : `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Now you can see error on the page.